# Ui file loaded by UiLoader , but NULL pointer to custom widgets

Tags: debugging, qt, qt-designer, ownership

i am using Qt 4.7.0 and windows7, 
i have a Huge problem with custom widgets, i founded QLed custom widget, i use it.

i want to add a signal properties to QLed widget and in design time with QtDesigner 
i want to add 100 QLed's on my Ui file and set each QLed's signal properties to a 
number(type of signal properties is not important), so i want to access this 100 QLeds
when i am coding and make a QList and access those

```
QFile file(":/test.ui");
QUiLoader loader;
file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
QWidget *formWidget = loader.load(&file, this);
file.close();
formWidget->show();
QList<QLed *> allQLed = formWidget->findChildren<QLed *>();
```

now i want to send data to QLeds

```
for(int i=0; i<allQLed.size(); i++){
    if(allQLed.at(i)->SIGNAL_PROPERTIES == 123)
        allQLed.at(i)->setValue(true);
    else    
        allQLed.at(i)->setValue(false);
}
```

now it will ON all QLeds that SIGNAL_PROPERTIES == 123

is my theory and metod incorect or i can do in other way?
i wrote my problem step by step
i changed dialog.cpp and cunstructor Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) : and *.pro file
i attached my test program.
Thanks.

*.pro file:

```
TARGET = example
TEMPLATE = app

QT += svg

CONFIG      += uitools

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        dialog.cpp\

HEADERS  += dialog.h\
            qled.h

FORMS    += dialog.ui

LIBS += libqledplugin

RESOURCES = test.qrc
```

** dialog.cpp

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"

#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QtUiTools>
#include "QLed.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

//---------------------------------------------------------------
        QFile file(":/test.ui");
        QUiLoader loader;
        file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
        QWidget *formWidget = loader.load(&file, this);
        file.close();
        formWidget->show();
        qDebug() << formWidget->children();

        QList<QCheckBox *> allCheckBox = formWidget->findChildren<QCheckBox *>();
        qDebug() << allCheckBox;
        qDebug() << allCheckBox.size();
        allCheckBox.at(2)->setChecked(true);
        QCheckBox *hello1 = formWidget->findChild<QCheckBox *>("checkBox_2");
        qDebug() << hello1;
        hello1->setChecked(true);

        QList<QLed *> allQLed = formWidget->findChildren<QLed *>();
        qDebug() << allQLed;
        qDebug() << allQLed.size();
        QLed *led = formWidget->findChild<QLed *>("qLed");
        qDebug() << led;
//---------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

i copied qledplugin-build-desktop\release folder files: qledplugin.dll, 
libqledplugin.a,
moc_qled.cpp, 
moc_qledplugin.cpp,
qrc_qled.cpp, 
moc_qled.o,
moc_qledplugin.o, 
qled.o,
qledplugin.o, 
qrc_qled.o,

to:

```
1) C:\QledTEST\my test program\mytest-build-desktop
2) C:\QledTEST\my test program\mytest-build-desktop\release
3) C:\QledTEST\my test program\mytest-build-desktop\debug
4) C:\Qt\2010.05\qt\include\QtGui
5) C:\Qt\2010.05\qt\include\Qt
6) C:\Qt\2010.05\qt\lib
7) C:\Qt\2010.05\qt\plugins\designer
```

, i can design a Ui dialog with QtDesigner and placing QLeds and QLabels, every thing is good, and i also can use other widgets. after it, i want to show this Ui file in my program, i am using UiLoader, i load Ui file in a QWidget object 
QWidget *formWidget = loader.load(&file, this);
and .show() it, 
in compile time i get this warnings in 1)Build Issues tab:

```
release/moc_qled.cpp:75: warning: 'QLed::staticMetaObject' redeclared without dllimport attribute after being referenced with dll linkage
release/moc_qled.cpp:84: warning: 'virtual const QMetaObject* QLed::metaObject() const' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored
release/moc_qled.cpp:89: warning: 'virtual void* QLed::qt_metacast(const char*)' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored
release/moc_qled.cpp:97: warning: 'virtual int QLed::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored
```

but my program work.
every thing is good, and my designed file is loading.
i use this command:

```
qDebug() << formWidget->children();
```

and i can see in 3) Application Output tab:

```
Starting C:\QledTEST\my test program\mytest-build-desktop\release\example.exe...
(QFormInternal::TranslationWatcher(0x14683d8) ,  QLed(0x1472320, name = "qLed_2") ,  QLed(0x14722a0, name = "qLed_3") ,  QLed(0x14723a0, name = "qLed_4") ,  QCheckBox(0x14810b8, name = "checkBox_2") ,  QCheckBox(0x14810d8, name = "checkBox_3") ,  QCheckBox(0x14810f8, name = "checkBox_4") ,  QLabel(0x1481118, name = "label") ,  QCheckBox(0x1481138, name = "checkBox") ,  QLed(0x14724e0, name = "qLed") )  
C:\QledTEST\my test program\mytest-build-desktop\release\example.exe exited with code 0
```

so i can see formWidget children, that containes QLeds my Custom Widgets.

now i need to send data to my QLeds and QCheckBoxs, 
i make a QList and try it:

```
QList<QCheckBox *> allCheckBox = formWidget->findChildren<QCheckBox *>();
qDebug() << allCheckBox;
qDebug() << allCheckBox.size();
allCheckBox.at(2)->setChecked(true); // i can send data
QCheckBox *hello1=formWidget->findChild<QCheckBox*>("checkBox_2");
qDebug() << hello1;
hello1->setChecked(true);// i can send data
```

i get:

```
(QCheckBox(0x14e10b8, name = "checkBox_2") ,  QCheckBox(0x14e10d8, name = "checkBox_3") ,  QCheckBox(0x14e10f8, name = "checkBox_4") ,  QCheckBox(0x14e1138, name = "checkBox") ) 
 4
QCheckBox(0x6f10b8, name = "checkBox_2")
```

it showes 4 QCheckBox

now i try Custom Widget:

```
QList<QLed *> allQLed = formWidget->findChildren<QLed *>();
    qDebug() << allQLed;
    qDebug() << allQLed.size();
```

i get:

```
() 
0 
QObject(0x0) //null pointer
```

my HUGE problem is here: 
allQLed.size() is zero
and i get null pointers

if i add QLed widget with coding i have no problem BUT i need QtDesigner.

i tested this on Q3Frame it is a custom widget plugin in QtDesigner and same problem.

why this happend and what can i do?
Qt cant do this?

thanks in advance
cheers

Comment: I'm not familiar with working with QtDesigner, but could you show the code where the QLeds are added to formWidget? I guess it's a generated file from QtDesigner.

Comment: I'm not sure enough to suggest this as an answer, but perhaps you don't have the QLed object linked into your application?  If so, the form won't be able to create them when it links dynamically, and so you would end up with no QLed objects.

Comment: QList<QLed *> allQLeds = formWidget->findChildren<QLed *>();

allQLeds size is zero, I think, it seems QLed class in formWidget and QLed class in main program are not one, they are different?! , I am Wrestleing with this problem for 2 weeks, I can't find any samples, (can it be a bug in Qt?), thanks in advanced.

Comment: i test this on Q3Frame (its a plugin in QtDesigner), and same problem.

Comment: I fix my problem by reading this link:
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/designer-using-a-ui-file.html
But I didnt use UiLoader,Regards Lopez.